# QRegularExpression escape Asterisk as Character

Tags: regex, qt, wildcard, qregularexpression

I'm trying to match strings which look either like this:

```
7;7;52*8    
8;8;62*5    
9;9;55*1    
11;7;52*49    
12;8;62*64    
14;9;54*62
```

or like this:

```
7;7;52    
8;8;62    
9;9;55    
11;7;52    
12;8;62    
14;9;54
```

I'm using the following code.

```
QRegularExpression re("(^\\d+;\\d+;\\d\\d$)|(^\\d+;\\d+;\\d\\d\\*\\d+$)");
QRegularExpressionMatch match;
```

matching the first part is working, but the second one seems to break at the asterisk part.

The following code is working for the regex search in notepad++

```
(^\d+;\d+;\d\d$)|(^\d+;\d+;\d\d\*\d+$)
```

Is there some special way to escape the asterisk character?

Comment: Are you trying to match *lines*? Then add `(?m)` at the pattern start (`"(?m)(^\\d+;\\d+;\\d\\d$)|(^\\d+;\\d+;\\d\\d\\*\\d+$)"`).

Comment: Your current regex can be written as `"^\\d+;\\d+;\\d\\d(?:\\*\\d+)?$"`, BTW.

Comment: thx guys. both your solutions work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you need to make the regex match the start and end of *lines*. The easiest way to fix the regex is to add `(?m)` inline modifier at the start of your pattern.

Note that your pattern contains redundant parts, you may use a regex with a single branch:

```
 "(?m)^\\d+;\\d+;\\d\\d(?:\\*\\d+)?$"
```

**Details**:

- `(?m)^` - start of a line
- `\\d+;\\d+;` - 1+ digits and `;` (2 times)
- `\\d\\d` - two digits
- `(?:\\*\\d+)?` - an optional sequence of a `*` and 1+ digits
- `$` - end of a line.